# Change a object by iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I try to change an object using an iterator, but I get this Error:

> Error 1   error C2662: 'void Item::setCount(int)' : cannot convert
>   'this' pointer from 'const Item' to 'Item &'
>
> 1   IntelliSense: the object has type qualifiers that are not
>   compatible with the member function

This is my code:

```
void Customer::addItem(Item other)//add item to the set
{
    set<Item>::iterator it;
    it = _items.find(other);

    if (it != _items.end())
    {
        it->setCount( (this->getCount((*it)) + 1) );
    }

    else
        _items.insert(other);
}
```

And in this line I have error:

```
it->setCount( (this->getCount((*it)) + 1) );
```

Comment: see the answer about mutable fields in const methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterator for an [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is `const`, since modifying the entry can impact the ordering.

To get around this, either :

- choose a different container
- do a delete+add operation (ie. remove the item from the set, modify it, and then add it into the set again)
- use [`mutable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) on the fields modified by `setCount` (if appropriate)
- use [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) to cast away the `const`ness of the item before calling `setCount` (as a last resort)

For the latter two options, make sure that `setCount` does not modify anything that changes the ordering of `Item` objects though.

Comment: Thanks you for comment.
What can i do if I want to update the counter of my item if I can't using set ?

Comment: @Yair - difficult to say without seeing your `Item` class, but your best bet is probably " choose a different container". In your case I would recommend removing the count from the item (after all, an item might have a name, a colour, a weight - but it typically doesn't have a count), and using `std::map<Item, int>` (or `unordered_map`) to store the counts.

Comment: @YairB. : I've added some more details to my answer, which will hopefully clarify things a bit better.